# onclick Listener doesn't work in fragments

Tags: java, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-button

I have implemented an onclicklistener on a button to open Gallery when I click the button in the app nothing happens

Code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statusfragment,container,false);
    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    view.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Upload screenshot",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        2000);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Choose Screenshot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1000);
                }
            }
        }
    });
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statusfragment, container, false);
}
```

it also does not display the Toast message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statusfragment, container, false);`
do `return view;`

Answer (score 1):

Very first try to do all the UI work in `onViewCreated()` method of `Fragment`.

Here you are not returning the initialized `view` above in the last and use `button` variable to implement click listener.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statusfragment,container,false);
    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Upload screenshot",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        2000);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Choose Screenshot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1000);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already initializing the `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statusfragment, container, false);` at the beginning and assigning it to `View view`, so just `return view;` at the end.